# LaunchImage not work

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have added two launch images to Images.xcassets in XCode5, but both not appear.
[image]

[image]

It's a iOS 7 game with landscape mode. I have tested it on simulator and iphone/ipad.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try cleaning your Project (Cmd+Shift+K) and run again.

Comment: @NikolaKirev I tried clean a lot now, still the same.

Comment: Also try (Cmd+Shift+Option+K) it cleans the build folder which I sometimes have problems with when working with App images.

Comment: @BenAvery thanks, but still not work.

Comment: try to delete the app from the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have changed the setting for your project so that it points to the Asset Catalog as the source for your Launch Image? If so, you should see the same as in the picture below.

[image]